# ADD-IN ERROR - This add-in cloud not be started. - CRITICAL

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

[image: Error from Outlook Client]

I have notice this error happens for **ALL** modern Outlook Office Add-ins. Searching the net I can also see that many other Modern Outlook Add-ins are having the same  issue. We know that this is an Outlook Client issue. You never get the error on OWA.

I have also seen that Microsoft are suggesting

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Click Tools
3. Click Internet Options
4. Click Security tab
5. Select Internet Sites zone
6. Select Enable Protected Mode (make sure box is un checked)
7. Click OK
8. Restart Internet Explorer and Outlook

However, we cannot ask customer to do this. Many are not even using IE. And it doesn't work most of the times!

In our case the Add-in service is running on Azure. We have enabled application insight and are monitoring failures on a daily basis. Our service is running on 20% of the avilable capacity. I feel that we have done all that we could. We are stock! and very frustrated.

Logically, when the Add-in works with no error in OWA,  and only fails in the Outlook client this can only mean the error is in Outlook or windows or.... **meaning it is a Microsoft error.**

Comment: Agree. It would be great to get any statistics on how many users are affected by this and add-in was not run.

Comment: Ekelund, can you give more details?  What Outlook client versions, what store apps can reproduce this error, what script errors do you see in the console.  Does this only affect Outlook desktop, or what browsers and versions does it also affect?  Which Outlook JS URL is being used - or is it a local distribution (and which version of Outlook JS?)  The screen capture is quite generic, I would not presume anything from it.

Comment: We don't have much details. It happens in different ways and only on desktop. It is IE related. The error doesn't happen on webmail. Users are being updated from O365, so the latest version. Searching, you will see it is a very OLD problem and has been for many years, hence many Outlook versions and JS versions. It happens for all Modern Office Add-ins. Yes even Microsoft own Findtime. I know it is a general problem. I have seen and heard of other Add-ins with the same problem. I really do believe this is a Microsoft problem and I would very much appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error is by-design for add-ins in Outlook clients that are rendered using IE and do not have Protected Mode enabled. Protected Mode is a security feature when using IE, and it is strongly recommend that it be enabled while using add-ins.

If you do not or cannot enable Protected Mode, a possible workaround is to upgrade to a newer Windows and Office, so add-ins are rendered using Edge Webview instead of IE. Details about what versions that Webview are supported can be found [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/).

Comment: Could you share the Outlook and windows version numbers where you're facing this issue? Also, IE requirement to be in protected mode is by design as mentioned above. It's a security feature which is required for add-ins to work. Most recent outlook and windows versions use edge instead of IE and shouldn't have this issue. Can you confirm the version numbers for both please

Comment: There are multiple reasons that could be causing this and unless we have more details it is difficult to get into the specifics of why your customers are facing this issue with every addin. We'd love to unblock you and understand the service impact, however we'd need more details. Also you mention that customers don't use IE yet you say it's IE related. Could you share the outlook &windoes build numbers your customer is on that's facing this issue? This happens for every addin and not just yours? Unless we have more information, it's very difficult for us to comment on what might be going on